# Renouncing the registration system

Tags: facebook, twitter, connections, registration

I want to completely remove the registration page from my web app (for obvious simplification and uniformity) and only use "connect with Facebook" and "connect with Twitter" the website is a technical one regarding the web and such so the public is somewhere above average (I presume), would this be a "safe" decision ?

Answer (score 2):

Depends if you mean safe as in secure, or safe as in for the benefit of your website.

In theory using twitter/facebook is more likely to be secure than rolling your own registration - this very website made the decision to [use openID](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/openid-does-the-world-really-need-yet-another-username-and-password.html) as supposed to rolling its own, so your in good company.

The most immediate thing which springs to mind is what if people don't have twitter or facebook?